# How to prevent post tumbnails images to load in wordpress when the viewport is less than 480px

Tags: php, wordpress, responsive-design, blogs

I am making an wordpress blog, and i want to prevent post-thumbnails images to load when the viewport is less or equal as the one of an phone device ( around 320px and 480px), currently the images are loaded and displayed in the desktop view ( 481px to so on), but i don't want to waste http requests when the blog is being viewed in an phone.

Answer (score 0):

check this: **(Picturefill) https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill** - didn't use/test
EDIT: http://wordpress.org/plugins/picturefillwp/faq/ - think you need to extend

Answer (score 0):

you can use a css media query to hide the images below the specified viewport dimenions. Something like this will work:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
img{display:none;}
}
</style>
```